# DbContext and Interface in HTTPPost action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using StructureMap for my dependency resolving. I am faced with an issue I don't know how to solve as the only way to make a form posting I understand will end up being without dependency injection which negate the whole essence of having StructureMap in my project.
The error is that I don't have `Add` method in my IdbContext Model. Below is my approach.

I have a Model named Module defined as below

```
   public class Module
   {
       public virtual int ID { get; set; }
       public virtual string Name { get; set; }
       public virtual DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
       public virtual string ModuleDescription { get; set; }
   }
```

and an interface defined as below.

```
    public interface ISolnetDataSource
    {
       IQueryable<Module> Modules { get; }
       void Save();
    }
```

A DbContext like below

```
     public class CMSDB : DbContext, ISolnetDataSource
      {
         public CMSDB() : base("DefaultConnection")
          {

          }

        public DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }

        void ISolnetDataSource.Save() 
           {
             SaveChanges();
           }

           IQueryable<Module> ISolnetDataSource.Modules
           {
              get { return Modules; }
           }              
      }
```

and my controller defined as

```
      [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CreateModulesViewModels module)
    {
        ViewBag.ListModule = _db.Modules.ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var model = new CreateModulesViewModels();

            var CreateModule = new Module();
            CreateModule.Name = module.Name;
            CreateModule.ModuleDescription = module.ModuleDescription;
            CreateModule.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            //_db.modules.Add(CreateModule);
            _db.Save();
            return View(model);
        }
        return View(module);
    }
```

The challenge I have with this is that I could'nt do  `_db.modules.Add(CreateModule)` (the commented line in the controller) so as to add a new record. What I'm doing wrong. I want to do this using the best approach applicable.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
_db.modules.Entry(CreateModule).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
```

Comment: `Entry` not also available. All I can access are the IQueryable methods from the look of things.

Comment: So maybe just make a manual sql query. The context has this option.

Comment: hmmmm ... I want to avoid using that. I want to use the project to learn as much as I can with LINQ and MVC structure.